# Powershell, check to see if a file contains more objects than in a list

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am creating a script that loops through files in a directory, reads them, and checks to see if they have groups not in an allowed list.

What I have so far is:

```
$allowedGroups = 'group1', 'group2', 'group3'
$AssignedValue = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExampleComputer\*.txt" 
ForEach ($file in $AssignedValue) {
    $contents = Get-Content $file | select -skip 6 
    if ($contents -notin $allowedGroups ){
        $contents | Out-file -Append -FilePath'C:\Users\user\Desktop\listofcomputers.txt'}


}
```

What I want to happen is if a file contains groups that are not in the allowedGroup list, it outputs it to a file. However it is just outputting all file contents. I also am having trouble adding the name of the file with the output, everything I have tried doesn't output the name

Thank you!

Comment: I think your issue is that `$contents` is an array not just one element. Likely you need another loop through all of `$contents` to check each element if it is in `$allowedgroups`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file name from a `$file` variable in your `Foreach` loop. To find the names of NOT allowed groups use `-notcontains` operator. And use `-join` operator to combine the array of such names into one string. 
Something like this:

```
$allowedGroups = 'group1', 'group2', 'group3'
$AssignedValue = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ExampleComputer\*.txt" 
ForEach ($file in $AssignedValue) {
    $contents = Get-Content $file | select -skip 6
    $notAllowedGroups = $contents  | where {$allowedGroups -notcontains $_} 
    if ($notAllowedGroups.Count -gt 0) {
        $reportForFile = $file.Name + ": " + ($notAllowedGroups -join ',')
        $reportForFile | Out-file  -FilePath 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\listofcomputers.txt' -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore the last comment, I just messed up on a spelling of a variable, the code works perfectly, thank you!